# symfony2- How to add all the field results at once when we create native querys

Tags: php, symfony

In a symfony2 project, lets say we have a native query and a ResultSetMapping as it follows:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('User', 'u');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'name', 'name');
...

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('SELECT id, name... FROM users', $rsm);
```

This lines works fine, but I'd like to know if is posible to add all the fields at once, without having to type every line.

Something like this:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('User', 'u');
$rsm->addFieldResults('u');
...

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM users', $rsm);
```

Comment: Why would you do this? It's the duty of ResultSetMapping to define the mapping. You have tons of possibilities when using Hydrators to hydrate according your desire. If you really want to achieve that I propose to create some helper function which is reading and running through all fields in your ClassMetaData. But honestly I don't see any sense in doing this.

Comment: I was just wondering if existed any function to do it because I prefer one line of code than one 'addFieldResult' line for each variable I want to retrieve... Now I have 25 addFieldResult lines and I would prefer just one. Is a good idea the helper function, I'll try it!

Comment: But why are doing this at all? What is the reasoning behind your approach?

Comment: I already found the way, there's a addRootEntityFromClassMetadata function which does exactly what I need. Sorry if I didn't know how to explain you. I was doing it because I needed  a nativequery to retrieve all the data from an entity, plus a cell with the avg's and counts of other tables (through a left join subquery). I wanted the new fields, but also the entity ones (And not having to type an 'addEntityResult' for each field)

Comment: fair enough, glad that you found what you need

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`ResultSetMappingBuilder`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder) object:

> An easy start into ResultSet mapping is the `ResultSetMappingBuilder` object. This has several benefits:
>
> - The builder takes care of automatically updating your `ResultSetMapping` when the fields or associations change on the metadata of an entity.
> - [...]

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('User', 'u');
```